# Repairing Hard to Find Faucet Cartridge

Tags: plumbing, sink

I bought a house and the sink leaks. I've searched everywhere and, as best I can tell, the leaky part is Pfister's 974-232 cartridge.

[image: Pfister 974-232]

I can't find this for sale anywhere, nor a suitable replacement.

The leak happens out of the end near the handle (the left side of the picture). Is there any straightforward way to repair the cartridge?

Comment: Contact Pfister, their number is online and see if there is a new part number for that. Builder.com is their replacement part supplier, they may have an answer as well